# Ricci deformation of hyperkahler ALE orbifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperkaehler, ricci-curvature

Let $(X^2,g)$ be a hyperkahler ALE orbifold surface. Consider its Ricci deformation equation:
$$
\Delta h+2Rm(h)=0
$$
for $\text{div}_g h=\text{Tr}_gh=0$ and $h=O(r^{-\epsilon})$ as $r \to +\infty$. Moreover, we require that $h$ is smooth at any orbifold point of $X$.

Given any such $h$, can we conclude that $h=0$ at any orbifold point?